# ASP.NET 4.0 VB Grid view not getting ID after sorting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

When I sort the grid view the UniqueID column remains where it is. I am using a separate page to edit and when I pass the UniqueID to that page to load the record it get the wrong record since the UniqueID was where it was before sorting. I read elsewhere about sorting and binding but it seems that is what I am doing. Any Ideas?

```
    Private Sub GridView2_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView2.Sorting

    Dim oldExpression As String = GridView2.SortExpression
    Dim newExpression As String = e.SortExpression

    If Session("SortExpression") <> e.SortExpression Then
        Session("SortExpression") = e.SortExpression
        ViewState("SortDirection") = Nothing
    End If

    If (ViewState("SortDirection")) Is Nothing Then
        If ViewState("SortDirection") = "ASC" Then
            ViewState("SortDirection") = "DESC"
        Else
            ViewState("SortDirection") = "ASC"
        End If
    Else
        If ViewState("SortDirection") = "DESC" Then
            ViewState("SortDirection") = "ASC"
        Else
            ViewState("SortDirection") = "DESC"
        End If
    End If

    '12/10/13 DBP 
    Dim SQLOrderByString As String = ""
    If e.SortExpression = "DateAwarded" Then
        SQLOrderByString = " Order by  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DateAwarded,101)  AS  smalldatetime) " & ViewState("SortDirection")
    Else
        SQLOrderByString = " Order by " & e.SortExpression & " " & ViewState("SortDirection")
    End If

    'note gblSQLAddNewString is created on page load so the column names are consistant
    Dim SQLWhereString As String = "Where Organization = '" & Session("Organization") & "' "

    Session("gblOrderByString") = SQLOrderByString
    Dim SQLCombinedString As String = gblSQLAddNewString & SQLWhereString & SQLOrderByString

    Me.GridView2.DataSource = PopulateGridwithSQL(SQLCombinedString)

    Me.GridView2.DataBind()

End Sub
```

''----------------- Additional code ---------
Session("EditSQLRecordID") has the correct ID of the top row prior to clicking a column heading to sort. After sorting when clicking the edit button on the grid, I can see the correct ID in the grid. but when I pause the code and examine the Session("EditSQLRecordID") variable, it is incorrect. Therefore I am eding the wrong record. The edit is taking place on a different page.

```
Private Sub GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView2.SelectedIndexChanged

    Try
        ' get the RowID of the grid this allows the choosing of a particular column value in the row chosen
        Dim RowID As Integer = GridView2.SelectedRow.RowIndex + 1

        ' Set session var to the SQL database record ID the last column (15) contains the SQL unique record ID
        '    this will be used to grab the record for editing
        Session("EditSQLRecordID") = GridView2.Rows(GridView2.SelectedIndex).Cells(17).Text
        Response.Redirect("EditGrid.aspx", False)

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim ErrorTitle As String = "Error"
        Dim PageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
        Dim Retval2 As String = ErrorTrap(PageName & " - " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message, ErrorTitle)

    End Try

End Sub
--------------------- Editing ----------------
   Private Sub GridView2_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowEditing
    Try
        ' get the RowID of the grid this allows the choosing of a particular column value in the row chosen
        Dim RowID As Integer = GridView2.SelectedRow.RowIndex + 1

        ' Set session var to the SQL database record ID the last column (15) contains the SQL unique record ID
        '    this will be used to grab the record for editing
        Session("EditSQLRecordID") = GridView2.Rows(GridView2.SelectedIndex).Cells(17).Text
        Response.Redirect("EditGrid.aspx", False)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ErrorTitle As String = "Error"
        Dim PageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
        Dim Retval2 As String = ErrorTrap(PageName & " - " & System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message, ErrorTitle)


    End Try

End Sub
```

----------- Added --------------
     Private Sub GridView2_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView2.PageIndexChanging

```
    Me.GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex

    ' 12/10/13 DBP 
    'note gblSQLAddNewString is created on page load so the column names are consistant
    Dim SQLWhereString As String = "Where Organization = '" & Session("Organization") & "' "

    ' 12-24-13 DBP added global sort since the Pages were out of order when sorting
    Dim SQLOrderByString As String = Session("gblOrderByString")
    '"Order by " & e.SortExpression & " " & ViewState("SortDirection")
    Dim SQLCombinedString As String = gblSQLAddNewString & SQLWhereString & SQLOrderByString

    Me.GridView2.DataSource = PopulateGridwithSQL(SQLCombinedString)

    Me.GridView2.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please give some more pointers on your question ?

Comment: added more code hope this helps. it has to do with clicking the edit button on the grid and it getting the oridinal sort of the grid prior to clicking a heading to sort it. the Uniqueid is what was in the grid prior. How do I sort and get the correct ID?

Comment: GridView2.Rows(GridView2.SelectedIndex).Cells(17).Text
is getting the correct ID only when the grid is not resorted.

Comment: how can I get the Row ID into this? ------------ Dim RowID As Integer = GridView2.SelectedRow.RowIndex + 1

                        '        Session("EditSQLRecordID") = GridView2.Rows(Row ID in here).Cells(17).Text